mkinitcpio and bundled files' location
after passing files to mkinitcpio via FILES or BINARIES in mkinitcpio.conf, where exactly do they end up?
let's say I added FILES=(/usr/lib/firmware/edid/abc.bin)
for example, with the above line:
# mkinitcpio -p linux
...
==> Creating zstd-compressed initcpio image: '/boot/initramfs-linux.img'
==> Initcpio image generation successful
# cpio -t < /boot/initramfs-linux.img
early_cpio
kernel/
kernel/x86/
kernel/x86/microcode/
kernel/x86/microcode/AuthenticAMD.bin
# ???

how can I make sure the generate init file do contain the file? And how can I be certain of the path to pass to kernel parameters?

not sure what cpio -t is supposed to be, but it doesn't list the contents. Maybe because they are compressed. Correct way is:
lsinitcpio /boot/initramfs-linux.img
This will show the files added from FILES as-is. That means it will show /usr/lib/firmware/edid/abc.bin in there.
How to point on kernel parameters depends on the module. Some have hardcoded predixes. for example, passing usr/lib/firmware/edid/abc.bin to drm.edid_firmware will cause "file not found", because it assumes the prefix "usr/lib/firmware/" by default, so you must pass only "edid/abc.bin".
